# Need help reading JSON object using ReactJS

Tags: json, reactjs

Need your expertise badly. I am creating an app where I need to read every item of the JSON response from an API. This is the format of the JSON

```
const data = [
  {
    "status": 1,
    "from": "2021-03-09T23:17:36.832Z",
    "to": "2021-03-10T01:24:41.193Z",
    "list": {
      "SG_2": {
        "name": "SG_2",
        "shift": "A",
        "status": 1,
        "cause": [
          "RMB"
        ],
        "performance": 2917.048,
        "shiftPml": 0.0390625,
        "dayPml": 0
      },
      "SG_1": {
        "name": "SG_1",
        "shift": "A",
        "status": 1,
        "cause": [
          "RMB"
        ],
        "performance": 2706.544,
        "shiftPml": 0,
        "dayPml": 0
      },
      "SG_3": {
        "name": "SG_3",
        "shift": "A",
        "status": 2,
        "cause": null,
        "performance": 0,
        "shiftPml": 0,
        "dayPml": 0
      }
    }
  }
];
```

And this is how I read the data

```
      {data.length > 0 && data.map((telemetry, index) => (
        <div>
          {telemetry.status} <br />
          {telemetry.from} <br />
          {telemetry.to} <br />
        </div>
))}
```

Can anyone help me how to read all the items, cause with my current i can't access the list part.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understood what's the problem. You have an access to `list` property via `telemetry.list`. It's an object though, so in order to traverse through it you can do next:

```
Object.values(telemetry.list).map((listItem) => {
  console.log(listItem.name, listItem.shift);
});
```

Comment: Hi Vlad, That another .map() will be placed inside the map, right?

Comment: Yes, it can be something like: <div>{telemetry.list.map(() => ....)}</div>

Comment: Hi Vlad, I add another map just like you did, however, I don't know why I get only ";" value.






```
      {data.length > 0 && data.map((telemetry) => (
        <div>
          {telemetry.status} <br />
          {telemetry.from} <br />
          {telemetry.to} <br />
          {
            Object.values(telemetry.list).map((listItem) => {
              <h1>{listItem.name, listItem.shift}</h1>
            })};
        </div>
      ))}
```

Comment: I've made an example for you in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-cloud-sfwtk)

Comment: I really appreciate it, Vlad. Thank you in a million ways. Have a great day.